# awk not printing the field expected... (at the moment nothing at all)

Tags: bash, awk

I know this appears a bit much for what I am trying to receive but it is part of a greater script so it is necessary to have the two set of awk commands piped the way they are.

Provided that I have an environment such as:

`interface=br1`

and my command being:

```
ip address show | awk '/\<inet\>/ { print $NF, '\t', $2 }' | awk '/\<"$(echo $interface)\>/ { print $3 }'
```

does anyone know why I can't get the appropriate IP output that I am expecting?

EDIT:

I wanted to edit this a bit to explain a bit more about what I am trying to do. I am pulling the information from `ip address show` to supply information to two different variables.

One variable is chosen by the user. That is the interface name.  The second variable is derived from the user's choice. and that derivative is directly placed into another command which is to be run at the end of the sequence.

To put it simply I am creating a commandline helper for virt-install.

The user chooses the bridge or interface they want to use with the VM and then that gets set to the `$interface` variable destined for the `--network=bridge:` flag.

However the console redirect is directly affected by the interface chosen. Therefore I have substituted this command in its place:

```
NETWORK=ip address show | awk '/\<inet\>/ { print $NF, '\t', $2 }'
.....
echo "Please choose your bridge interface"
$NETWORK
printf "Interface: ": read interface
......
--graphics vnc,listen=`$NETWORK | awk -v i=$interface '/\<i\>/ { print $2 }'`,port=5910,keymap=jp
```

Comment: Shell variables aren't expanded in single quotes (nor do I see how having two awk commands there is, or can be, at all necessary). Also `$(echo $variable)` is almost completely pointless as `$variable` does the same thing for almost all cases (and those where it doesn't you probably didn't want the difference anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 `awk` because you can filter what you want in one step

```
export interface=br1
ip address show | awk '/\<inet\>/ && $NF == interface { print $NF, '\t', $2 }' interface="$interface"
```

or, you can just provide the interface to `ip`

```
ip address show $interface | awk '/\<inet\>/ { print $NF, '\t', $2 }'
```

### EDIT

If you only want the IP address without the mask

```
ip address show $interface | awk '/\<inet\>/ { sub("/.*$", "", $2); print $2; }'
```

Try

```
man awk
```

to see the available functions.

Comment: Makes sense, I`ll give it a try.  I've become use to using awk, but my skill level with it is likely only just beyond beginner so many times its hard for me to imagine being able to do something in one command as opposed to two.

Ill let you know how it goes.

Comment: by the way I feel a bit stupid for not providing that interface to ip.... however now I can just specify field 2 and make sure to use the cut command to receive just the IP address.  I'm trying to get more and more into awk so I greatly appreciate the help.  once I get the kinks worked out Ill post back and accept your answer.

Comment: It worked like ip address show | awk '/\<inet\>/ && $NF == interface { print $2 }' interface="$interface" | cut -d / -f 1`

I could have used awk again specifiying the seperator as "/" but then I would have wanted to do it within the first command if possible and... I don't know if it is for a one liner like that.

Answer (score 0):

Two-point-six suggestions:

1. Try print instead of echo
2. awk doesn't give you environment variables for free, so you'll need to pass your variable in. Once you do that, don't use the dollar sign when you use your variable:

awk -v intf=$interface '{ print intf }'

Comment: I didn't know this about awk.  I figured since it was a fairly common program to use within the shell environment it would naturally use the environment variables.  This is what I get for assuming.  In anycase Ill give it a try and let you know how it works.  Thanks

Comment: The result seems to have been the same as my previous try... its possible variables can't be utilized within the awk REGEXP matching field?